# Dictionary<string, List<Tuple<string, int>>> dict_Info_A = new Dictionary<string,List<Tuple<string,int>>>();

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary

I am using Dictionary with tuple as a parameter.

```
Dictionary<string, List<Tuple<string, int>>> dict_Info_A = 
new Dictionary<string,List<Tuple<string,int>>>();
```

I am not able to initialize it ,complilation errors are coming.
Please suggest some way of initializing it.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: which exception bro & paste your code plz

Comment: stop undoing the code edit, your code is not completely visible if you are not going to enclose it in the code blocks

Comment: There are no compilation errors in defining the above dictionary, how are you using it and what is the error you are getting

Comment: This is the implementation I am using. 
dict_Info_A.Add("A", new Tuple<string,int>("hello", 1));

Comment: @savalakh, You are adding wrong type to dictionary value. Try this:dict_Info_A.Add("A", new List<Tuple<string, int>>() { new Tuple<string, int>("hello", 1) });

Answer (score 4):

This is how you'd use a collection initializer to initialize your dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Tuple<string, int>>> dict_Info_A = new Dictionary<string, List<Tuple<string, int>>>
{
    { "a", new List<Tuple<string, int>> { new Tuple<string, int>("1", 1) } } 
    { "b", new List<Tuple<string, int>> { new Tuple<string, int>("2", 2) } } 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should decide first, what dictionary you need

1. either mapping `string` to `List<Tuple<string,int>>`
2. or mapping `string` to `Tuple<string,int>`

---

With this line of code

```
dict_Info_A.Add("A", new Tuple<string,int>("hello", 1));
```

you're trying to use `Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, int>>`

Such dictionary should be initialized like this:

```
var dict_Info_A = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, int>>();
```

---

Here is the dictionary you showed in the original question:

Init the dictionary using [var](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) keyword:

```
//you can also omit explicit dictionary declaration and use var instead
var dict_Info_A = new Dictionary<string, List<Tuple<string, int>>>();
```

Init an element of the dictionary:

```
dict_Info_A["0"] = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();
```

Add elements to a list from the dictionary:

```
dict_Info_A["0"].Add(new Tuple<string, int>("asd", 1));
```

Comment: Looks like I don't have the required reference/dll to use 'var' keyword.

Comment: @savalakh, what version of .Net are compiling with? In the end, you  still use explicit declaration. All other parts of code remain the same

Answer (score 0):

You can't use (comments):

```
dict_Info_A.Add("A", new Tuple<string,int>("hello", 1));
```

because the dictionary wants, as the value, a **list**. You *could* do something like:

```
List<Tuple<string,int>> list... // todo...
     // for example: new List<Tuple<string, int>> { Tuple.Create("hello", 1) };
dict_Info_A.Add("A", list);
```

If you need multiple values per key, and want to *append* to this list then maybe:

```
List<Tuple<string,int>> list;
string key = "A";
if(!dict_Info_A.TryGetValue(key, out list)) {
    list = new List<Tuple<string,int>>();
    dict_Info_A.Add(key, list);
}
list.Add(Tuple.Create("hello", 1));
```